# Why I have this error with Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

In this website, I want to load my pages with JQuery and Ajax by clicking on a menue point.

The problem is, that I have errors by loading it.
What does the Error **"GET 'path to css file'"** in the console mean?
(there is some Ajax code by clicking on error)

It seems that the browser doesn't load the whole css file in the content.
I hope that you can help me, because I don't now what could be wrong.

Here is my code:

JQuery/Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("menue li > a").click(function(){
   var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

    if(hash){
      console.log(hash);
      $(document.body).load("js/sv_index.php",  {id:hash});
  }
 });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
  $id = $_POST['id'];

  switch($id){
    case ("index"):
        include '../index.php';
        break;

    case("tutorials"):
        include '../php/tutorials.php';
        break;

    case("news"):
        include '../php/news.php';
        break;

    case("terminal"):
        include '../php/terminal.php';
        break;

    case("anmeldung"):
        include '../php/anmeldung.php';
        break;
  }
?>
```

Comment: P.S: Index is working right without errors.

Comment: It means the path to your stylesheet is wrong. My guess is without seeing the href attribute is that its something like "some/path/to/stylesheet.css" while your including from a parent directory. So try to make the path be "/some/path/to/stylesheet.css" or even "[full_domain]/some/path/to/stylesheet.css"

Comment: My Stylesheet file is included in the files with tutorials.php etc. Why it does should be wrong? It always loaded correctly by them self.

Comment: Okay, you're right. Sry for this stupid question. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that the web page is looking for your CSS file in 'path to CSS file' and doesn't find it there.  Are you sure that your CSS link goes to the correct location and that your server is properly configured to serve the static files?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Avoid asking questions in your answer. Use comments to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have solved it and it works :). Stackoverflow is very nice for getting fast answers :). The problem was my wrong css path, how as you said.